# Can Mac Mini Server be booted off either of its two disks?

Tags: linux, multi-boot, mac-mini, osx-server

Can a Mac Mini, Server edition, be booted off either of its two disks?

I'm interested in having one disk with OSX Server on it, and the other a dual boot Linux/Windows, to get around OSX's fussiness about boot loaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

For OSX just install again on the other disk then System Preferences-> Startup disk will offer a choice.

For Windows install via BootCamp and the Windows disk wiull show in the startup volumes.

For Linux you might have to look at [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: And what happens at boot time: how do I choose between the disks?

Comment: I don;t know re rEFIt but for OSX and Bootcamp - in OSX choose Startup disc in System Preferences or in Windows choose on Bootcamp Icon or control panel. Or on boot hit Option (aka alt ) http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1310

Comment: OK, that tells me what I want to do is possible.

Comment: Note: OSX Server isn't supported by Bootcamp.  REFIT seems to be the way to go.